# Check Personal Geodatabase attribute against external MySQL database?

Tags: fields-attributes, mysql, personal-geodatabase

I have a Personal Geodatabase to which editors enter values from some field inputs.

I would like some of the entries, eg Project No ( whose name is unique and has some some related attributes like contractor etc ) to be checked against an MySQL database and pop up properties of that Project number from External DB to be available for comparison during data entry..

This would help to avoid wrong Project name entry , double check whether its the Same project which is currently being entered, based on related properties.

I had a conversation with the Developer of the External Web application from where we want to fetch the data - Its a PHP application having a MySQL database at backend. So basically I would need to have a secure Login from the ArcGIS editing Window/Session.

Does this warrant a different approach?

Comment: It would help to have a bit more detail.  Since it is a Personal GDB, I assume you are using ArcGIS?  If so, what version?  Is the Oracle database an SDE database, or simply stand-alone?  What have you tried?  Part of what makes GISse work best is the users being able to build off of what someone has already attempted, to help them reach an answer.  If you have already tried a couple of things, but they didn't work, please include that information, as that would prevent someone suggesting a duplicate idea.  On the other hand, if you have an idea for a process, include that as well.

Comment: It sounds like you want to write an [editor extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000019m000000) using ArcObjects. Check out some of the [samples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004n0000000), [walkthroughs](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000391000000), etc. in the ArcObjects SDK Help. If you're not an ArcObjects developer already then you have a steep learning curve ahead of you...

Comment: Hi Blah238 , Please see my edited comment and would that change your above comment/solution to the Question ?

Comment: I don't think that changes anything except which database you need to access (MySQL instead of Oracle). Is there someone else in your organization that knows both ArcGIS development and database access? They would be able to help you much more easily than anyone here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to load in the MySQL DB table into Arc to compare feature attributes.  You should be able to add the table using OLE DB connection, see link below.

[Adding OLE DB connections to databases](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000452000000)